# Second order fixed-point problem

Tags: algorithms, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Let's say we have the following fixed-point problem: find $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies
$$
y = p + f(y)
$$
where $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a constant and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. In this case, $f(\cdot)$ has a special property, where it's second derivative is constant, i.e. $\partial^3 f_i / \partial y_j \partial y_k \partial y_l = 0$ (note that the subscript indicates the index of the element, e.g. $f_4$ is the 4-th output of $f(\cdot)$). Let's say we can code how to compute various things, such as jacobian-vector product and hessian-vector-vector(?) product, but cannot store the Jacobian matrix nor the Hessian 3D tensor explicitly.

Is there an algorithm that's designed specifically for this type of problem?

I know some algorithms such as Broyden, Anderson acceleration, etc, they are designed for general fixed-point or root-finding problem and they use the first-order approximation. The problem is, we need to tune the parameters of those algorithms to make it work for a specific case.

Comment: Maybe you can apply Newton's method to the function $y\mapsto f(y)-y-p$?

Comment: Due to the size, we can’t store the jacobian matrix explicitly, so one step in Newton’s method requires an implicit inverse algorithm which involves multiple inner iterations. It might be too slow to converge.

Comment: So $n$ is very very large?

Comment: Yes, it’s usually enough to store the vector but not the matrix